# Import log4j.Logger in Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, log4j

I am trying to build a simple java application in eclipse that uses log4j to make logs (I intend to export it as a jar file).

But when I try to import org.apache.log4j.Logger in the java file, I get an error as follows

[image]

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: is that jar included in bulid path of your project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve this Log4J import error (relating to Classpath too)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270618/how-do-i-resolve-this-log4j-import-error-relating-to-classpath-too)

Comment: it should work, clean the project please...

Comment: In Eclipse, check if "Project" -> "Build automatically" is checked.

Comment: You also need an API for log4j to work

Answer (score 0):

You can find the class "org.apache.log4j.Logger" in the log4j-X.X.XX.jar

This jar must be included in your build path.

If you have a maven project you can just add a dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Otherwhise you have to download the jar and add the jar manually to your build path.

Comment: He is not using maven - there is no pom.xml on the screenshot. And also project is just simple `Java Project` not the `Maven project`

Answer (score 0):

Not web project, I mean, in plain Java project, it don't know the import jar file automatically. It mean, as to your structure, having jar in **lib** folder is not enough. You need to add this jar under **lib** folder manually to your **class path.**

You can do manually like this:

```
ProjectRightClick>>Build Path>>Configure Build Path>>Click Add Jar>>choose your log4 jar under lib folder>> OK.
```

Hope it help.

Comment: after that, can you see your log4 jar under Referenced library? can you finished rebuild project?

Comment: Yes, it's there under Referenced Library. I built the project too but the error's still there

Comment: can you expend your jar under referenced library and you must see org.apache.log4j.Logger class. if not, jar is not valid.

Comment: When I expand the jar under Referenced Library, there's a a META-INF folder and a lib package which contains the log4j1.2.17.jar but there's no classes in there. I changed the jar, added it to the build path and built the project again. but it still stays the same.

Comment: It's insane, you have to make sure your jar is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download log4j package from link given below

http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/2.11.0/apache-log4j-2.11.0-bin.zip

and then left click on your project logtestjava > properties > Java build path > classpath > add all jars of log4j package